# responsive site on resize slider not working

Tags: jquery, css, html, window-resize

I am making a  responsive HTML5 [website](http://datumtech-cnc.com/html5_development), currently only home page and aerospace page is done. I am using 2 sliders on home page. 1st is visible till certain screen size then it becomes invisible and 2nd slider is displayed. If I change the screen size to mobile screen size and click on any link then resize to original size, the 1st slider won't load.

Comment: here is the link to the website. http://datumtech-cnc.com/html5_development/

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure this out? If not, you can try the [Liquid Slider](http://liquidslider.kevinbatdorf.com/) which adapts to screen sizes.